# How to access android device front camera using flash actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, camera

Hi friends, I have already created a camera application for web application using flash as3. It works fine and using the camera class for Camera.getCamera(); And now I want to create this same application for android. I have android device with front facing camera only. So the same application I have run  in my device. I can't see the camera display. Is there any options I can use to access front camera on my device?

Answer (score 1):

use the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera%28%29)!
The Camera.getCamera()'s description states:

```
Parameters
name:String (default = null) — Specifies which camera to get, as determined from the array returned by the names property. For most applications, get the default camera by omitting this parameter. To specify a value for this parameter, use the string representation of the zero-based index position within the Camera.names array. For example, to specify the third camera in the array, use Camera.getCamera("2").
```

So if you want the second camera, use

> Camera.getCamera("1")

Answer (score 0):

Camera index is the number which define back camera or front camera. the first index may be the back camera and the second item may be the front camera or vice-a-versa.

If I were to guess, I'd say that you use the [Camera class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html).. [post on this Blog gives you a more information](http://www.riagora.com/2010/07/android-air-and-the-camera/)

May this will help you..!